# Problems running epstopdf. Check your TeX installation

Tags: c#, pdf, documentation, latex, doxygen

I keep getting the following error when running doxygen:

```
Problems running epstopdf. Check your TeX installation!
```

Do I need to install Latex somewhere?

Comment: I have the same problem with running `doxygen doxygen.config` in Windows 10 for c++ code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`epstopdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf) is a Perl script that converts EPS to 'encapsulated' PDF using GhostScript. Technically you don't need LaTeX, although it forms part of every TeX distribution by default.

So, either download it directly, or install any one of the major TeX distributions (say, [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/) or [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html)).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this when playing around with plantuml (@startuml, @enduml).
In the default config, GENERATE_LATEX is set to YES, whereas I only cared for html. 
When I set GENERATE_LATEX to NO, doxygen does not need epstopdf anymore.